# How to access and edit an object value by iterating on a path?

Tags: javascript, object, react-hooks, properties, propertypath

Having this following data structure :

```js
const foo = [
    {
        a: 'xxx',
        b: 'xxx',
        c: {
            e: 'xxx',
            ...
        }
    }
    ...
]
```

Is it possible to access the value of `e` with this path object

```js
const path = [0, 'c', 'e']
```

and edit it ?

I tried by doing

```js
setResponseState(prevState => {
    let data = prevState.responseData
    path.forEach(id => data = data[id])

    data = {}
    return prevState
})
```

`path` being a context value but I found out `data` was a copy and therefore wasn't saved in the react state

Thank you

Comment: `foo[0]['a']['e']` is undefined. Try your existing code with the path `[0, 'c', 'e']` instead. Your existing code looks like it should work, if you take away the last two lines and just `return data`.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. yeah it was a mistake in this example... I know how to access the data. The problem is how to access AND edit it in the original object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you modify updating the last value in `forEach` as below should work for editing the object. Basically this avoid overriding the object reference and only update the value.

```
const foo = [
  {
    a: "xxx",
    b: "xxx",
    c: {
      e: "xxx",
    },
  },
];


const path = [0, "c", "e"];

setResponseState((prevState) => {
  let data = prevState.responseData;
  path.forEach((id, i) =>
    i === path.length - 1 ? (data[id] = {}) : (data = data[id])
  );
  return prevState;
});
```

Check this sample mutating the object

```js
const foo = [
  {
    a: "xxx",
    b: "xxx",
    c: {
      e: "xxx",
    },
  },
];

const path = [0, "c", "e"];


  let data = foo;
  path.forEach((id, i) =>
    i === path.length - 1 ? (data[id] = {}) : (data = data[id])
  );

console.log(foo)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to access the value, your existing code is mostly fine, you just need to return the value.

```js
const foo = [
    {
        a: 'xxx',
        b: 'xxx',
        c: {
            e: 'xxx',
        }
    }
]

const path = [0, 'c', 'e']

function setResponseState(prevState) {
    let data = foo; //prevState.responseData
    path.forEach(id => data = data[id])
    return data;
};

console.log(setResponseState());
```

Comment: Thanks but I want to edit the value I'm accessing... This is a set function call from a React Hook state object

Answer (score 0):

This (accessing a nested value via a provided path) is a standard task for the very expressive [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method in collaboration with [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining#syntax) in order to ensure a fail safe implementation ...

```js
const foo = [{
  a: "zzz",
  b: "yyy",
  c: {
    e: "xxx",
  },
}];

console.log({ foo });
console.log(
  '[0, "c", "e"].reduce((value, key) => value?.[key], foo) ...',
  [0, "c", "e"].reduce((value, key) => value?.[key], foo)
);
console.log(
  '[0, "C", "e"].reduce((value, key) => value?.[key], foo) ...',
  [0, "C", "e"].reduce((value, key) => value?.[key], foo)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

If it comes to mutating an object's nested property, one preferably would utilize the above approache within a function ...

```js
const foo = [{
  a: "zzz",
  b: "yyy",
  c: {
    e: "xxx",
    f: "uuu",
  },
}];

function assignValueToExistingNestedProperty(type, path, value) {
  const [lastKey, ...keyList] = path.reverse();

  // access the next to last property value.
  const reference = keyList
    .reverse()
    .reduce((value, key) => value?.[key], type);

  Object.assign((reference ?? {}), { [lastKey]: value });

  return type;
}

console.log({ foo });
console.log(
  'assignValueToExistingNestedProperty(foo, [0, "c", "e"], "AAA") ...',
  assignValueToExistingNestedProperty(foo, [0, "c", "e"], "AAA")
);
console.log(
  'assignValueToExistingNestedProperty(foo, [0, "C", "e"], "BBB") ...',
  assignValueToExistingNestedProperty(foo, [0, "C", "e"], "BBB")
);
console.log({ foo });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: @AlexisChoupault ... you might have a look at the above reduce based solution(s).